# AI in protection relays

Tags: electrical-engineering

I have been doing research into artificial Intelligence applications for protection relays. I have read a lot about theory and the possibility of them being used, but have failed to find evidence of it ever being implemented. Can anyone point me to some information on actual implementations and statistics on its usage.

Comment: You could begin by telling us what protection relays are. ;-)  Any type of relay can be used as a simple kill switch when activated ( or de-activated) by a control signal.